# setting dynamic observables with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    $.getJSON("/categories", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, cat) {
            self[cat] = ko.observable(true);
        });
    });
}
```

The data coming in is a JSON array of category names - I have confirmed in my console log that those are coming through just fine.

In my template though, when I use the `visible: viewModel[catname]` data binding, nothing happens. Not getting any errors though. Any ideas?

--

Note:

Actual template (rails3):

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %> 
<div data-bind="visible: viewModel[<%=category.name%>]">
<%= category.name %>
</div> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Uh, this is probably because in the data-binding, `catname` has no value. Can you post the rest of your template. This might not be doable. Is there some reason you don't want to use an `observableArray` to hold all the cats?

Comment: I'm rendering the cat name in the data-binding through rails. I need the names to be true/false observable, is there a way to do that with the array?

Comment: Ok, I see. Yes there is a way to do with with the array, but try just removing the `viewModel` from the binding. If the template is being rendered by the server, you just bind `visible: <%=category.name%>`. If that works, I will post more detail in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding should just be `visible: catname`. All bindings are already "scoped" within `viewModel`, so you don't need to reference it in the bindings.

See my working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/WpdMZ/. Note that `banana` and `pear` are set to `true`, so their corresponding squares are visible, but `apple` is set explicitly to `false`, so its square is not visible.

---

In light of your update, you should be able to change this line:

```
<div data-bind="visible: viewModel[<%=category.name%>]">
```

To this:

```
<div data-bind="visible: <%=category.name%>">
```

Comment: yep, I was going to answer the same thing.  `viewModel` is your context when you're setting a binding.

Answer (score 0):

Jackie is correct, but you should really consider a more consistent approach. If your data is coming in, place it in knockout models, and use the knockout templating. Here is a fiddle demonstrating this method: http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/W6SXU/3/